# Can't Keep Count Without Metronome

Tags: rhythm, metronomes

(Please bear with me; I don't know a lot of sheet music.)

When practicing a song that has 16 notes per bar (

), I can do it with the metronome and can count with it.
The problem comes when I turn the metronome off; I can't keep track.

You see, the intro is pretty quiet, so it's harder to keep track of the rhythm, and I mess up.

How do people keep in time in such intros?

Comment: Practice more.  Practice in bits.  Shift the metronome from 1 beat per note to 2 beats per note, etc.

Comment: can you sing the part in time without the metronome? I had a teacher that always said, if you can't sing it, you can't play it.  and it is pretty true. slow it down, sing it and then play it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to stomp the rythm with your foot on the strong beats (1,2,3,4).

Try turning the metronom off for some bars and turn it on again. Check if you are still in sync with the metronom.

I was always struggling with the rythm too. What helped me really, was to subdivide the bars. I didn't see the bars as "one", "two", "three", "four", i look at them like "one", "and", "two" "and" [..], or even "one", "e", "and", "a", "two", "e", "and", "a" [...].

This will ofc need some time but sooner or later you will develope a feeling in your head. What i mean you will no longer need to count the bars in your head like "one", "two", "three", "four", its more like you are just feeling it.

When there is much room where nothing is palyed, its harder to keep in sync. One more trick i am using for this is to hum a melody in my head, which i can use to fill the gaps and keep in sync.